# How to initialize / instantiate a late client socket in flutter without connecting it to any host

Tags: flutter, sockets

So, I'm developing this flutter app where I want to declare a Socket client on MyApp class and carry it to every other page of my app. I want to have a page to connect the socket to the server, but it's not my home page. I tried declaring it inside MyApp like this:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  late final Socket client;

  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: MyColors.green,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      routes: {
        '/': (_) => DefaultHomePage(),
        '/connection_page': (_) => ConnectionPage(client: client),
        '/evaluation_page': (_) => Evaluation(client: client),
        '/settings_page': (_) => SettingsPage(client: client),
      }
    );
  }
}
```

and only connect it to a server when I press the connection button inside my ConnectionPage:

```
Card(
                child: ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.wifi,  size: 40,),
                  title: Text("Connect to Wi-Fi", style: TextStyle(height: 1, fontSize: 20),),
                  subtitle: Text('Here is a second line'),
                  tileColor: MyColors.green[800],
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                  ),
                  onTap: () async {
                    await showIPDialog(context);
                    client = await Socket.connect(_textEditingController.text, 3333);


                  },
                ),
                shadowColor: const Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 0),
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(left:20, right:20, top: 10),
              ),
```

But I'm having this error:

```
LateError (LateInitializationError: Field 'client' has not been initialized.)
```

How can I initialize my socket without connecting it to a server right away? Or never even connecting it at all.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, it was actually very simple once you figured I out with the help of a friend.
The only thing I had to do was declare Socket? client and pass it to the classes constructors where I have the attribute Socket?.